# Is there a way for a listview to add items Vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox

this code is a bubble sort, which sorts from one listbox to the next listbox. Listbox1 is unsorted and listbox2 is sorted.

```
 Dim outpt1 As String = ""
    Dim ListOfString As New List(Of String)
    Dim alItems As New ArrayList

    ''Create list of strings (in this case, characters)
    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Me.ListBox1.SetSelected(i, True)
        ListOfString.AddRange(ListBox1.Items(i).Split(" "))
    Next
    ''Sort and format
    For Each bub As String In BubbleSortString(ListOfString)
        outpt1 += bub & " "
    Next


    ListBox2.Items.Add(outpt1)
```

The code adds the unsorted list into the sorted list box all in one row. it needs to be one row for each item. Any help is much appreciated thanks

Comment: The title says "listview" but there's no `ListView` in your code. Provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem, which includes not telling us that you're using controls that you're not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you think is happening is not happening. It's not that multiple items are being added in a single row. Look at your code. Read it! How many times do you call `ListBox2.Items.Add`? Once. So how many items are you adding? One! Think about what you are actually doing. `outpt1` is a `String` and you are concatenating values to that `String`. Once you've concatenated all the values you then add that one `String` to the `ListBox`.

If that's not what you want then don't do it. Get rid of that `String` variable and just add each value directly to the `ListBox`. That's what you actually want - to add the items to the `ListBox` - so do that.

```
For Each bub As String In BubbleSortString(ListOfString)
    ListBox2.Items.Add(bub)
Next
```

The code you have is what you end up with when you write code without knowing what it has to do, i.e. not just the result but the steps to get there. That's why you should work out the logic first, write it down if you need to, then write code to implement that logic. If you had done that, there's no way that your algorithm would have included a step that said to join all the items into a single string.

Comment: Thankyou so much. this has really helped out I appreciate it heaps thanks

Answer (score 0):

I filled a list box with strings containing a space.

The array returned by Split is added to the List(Of String). A note here, turn on Option Strict for this code and all your code. `Items` in a `ListBox` are `Object`s so we need `.ToString` so that `.Split` can be used. The small `c` following the `Split` parameter tells the compiler that this is a `Char` which is what `Split` is expecting.

Next, I used the `Sort` method on `List(Of String)` and added the sorted list to `ListBox2`.

The debug is to show the contents of my ListBox2.

```
Private lst As New List(Of String) From {"Mathew Smith", "Mark Jones", "Luke Name", "John Peter"}

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lst.ToArray)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ListOfString As New List(Of String)
    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        ListOfString.AddRange(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString.Split(" "c))
    Next
    ListOfString.Sort()
    ListBox2.Items.AddRange(ListOfString.ToArray)
    For Each item In ListBox2.Items
        Debug.Print(item.ToString)
    Next
    'Result in Immediate Window
    'John
    'Jones
    'Luke
    'Mark
    'Mathew
    'Name
    'Peter
    'Smith
End Sub
```